# Convert file path to UTF-8

Tags: c#, .net, utf-8, utf-16, utf

I want to get, print and write to a text file the full path on disk of a file named `A&T+X-8_L_R1.png` but when I print it I get `A&amp;T+X-8_L_R1.png`.

AFAIK I need to change the encoding. I did a search and found this potential solution but it doesn't work:

```
String filePathString = relativeUri.ToString();

byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(filePathString);
filePathString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
filePathNode.SetValue(filePathString);
```

This is the full code of my class: http://pastebin.com/dZLGeS8p

The class searches recursively for `*.png` files and creates an `XML` structure from their paths. When I save the `XML` file the special characters from the paths like `&` are changed.

Can anyone point me to a solution?

Comment: Where do you *print it*? Opening and saving to a file named `A&T+X-8_L_R1.png` (for example using `File.WriteAllText` works. What is `filePathNode`?

Comment: Please show the code that *gets, prints and writes*.

Comment: @pasty I don't want to write to a file named `A&T+X-8_L_R1.png`. I want to write the string `A&T+X-8_L_R1.png` inside a file.

Comment: This is entirely normal and required for an XML file.  I'm guessing you are looking at the file with a text editor.  The &amp; gets converted back to & when you properly read the XML file.

Comment: @Hans Passant So you are saying that this is because of my XML viewer? I would like to see it as `&` instead of `&amp;`.
Why wouldn't I want to see `&` instead of `&amp;`?

Comment: If you want to use your eyes instead of a computer to read text then use a file format that was made for eyes.  Like a .txt file, a Microsoft Word document, a PDF file.  XML was made for computers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing an XML file, not a plain text file. In XML, an ampersand needs to be escaped to `&amp;`.

So the result you get is perfectly ok. It's even required to be like this.

I recommend to open the XML file with an application that can properly validate and display XML. It'll be easier to see that the file is correct.

The UTF-8 conversion in your code isn't required. If the XML file is encoded in UTF-8, your XML classes will take care of any required conversions.